# Is it possible to use a SD card as virtual memory in OS X Server?

Tags: macos, sd-card, virtual-memory, server.app

I have a 8gb High Performance SD card that I would like to use as swap (virtual memory).  Is this possible in Mac OS X Server, and if so how do I go about doing this?

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? It seems like a horrible idea - even a high performance SD card isn't going to be as fast as a hard drive, and having a non-standard configuration that wasn't tested by Apple is just begging for trouble.

Comment: Look here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/1469/14994

Comment: My advice - don't do this. Even if SD card appears fast, it's when writes are aligned and full blocks. Those cards are designed to do large sequential reads/writes, in those scenario they are useless (very low IOPS with small blocks).

Comment: Get an SSD for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably **can** use an SD card as a backing store.

However: you should **not** expect a good result. See the up-voted comments.

Answer (score 0):

No - the Mac OS doesn't have an accelerate feature where extra storage swaps files (or anything else for that matter). The best you could do is try to disable swap - move the swapfile directory to the card and re-start the dynamic pager.

Here are a few questions to get you started:

- [Why would I disable swap file in Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24502/why-would-i-disable-swap-file-in-mac-os-x)
- [How can I move virtual memory swap files to a different drive or partition?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/how-can-i-move-virtual-memory-swap-files-to-a-different-drive-or-partition)

Also - for the purposes of VM mechanics, the server OS and the normal OS behave the same.

Comment: I'd love to see some stats on whether this speeds things up or not. Several well respected developers have been dabbling with disabling the dynamic_pager entirely as their macs have become gunked up and slow. I don't have a good tuning guide or know if there's even a problem with the default paging setup or they have odd setups where other things are exacerbating the VM's overhead. My guess is all the new Lion things have introduced some extra complexity that can cause undesirable performance more so than in the past. Time will tell if this is so...

Comment: I would like these details as well, as this is the motivating reason why I'm looking into doing this.

Comment: When I experimented in Mountain Lion, having swap enabled would indeed make the system *faster*, albeit *less responsive* when actually swapping as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'll do.

a) Disable VM

b) Delete the original folder where the system stores swap files

c) Create a alias to a folder in the SD Card and change its name to match the folder you deleted.

d) Enable VM and see if it works, if it doesn't it PROBABLY won't crash the system, VM SHOULD simply fall back and NOT turn on.

I strongly don't recommend this, SD Card won't be any faster than HD in terms of performance.

I will recommend alias (if it works), because that way you can just delete the alias if you changed your mind.

Comment: In Super User: [Should I symlink my /private/var/vm dir to another volume in OS X Lion?](http://superuser.com/q/337674/84988)