# Should I disable Virtual Memory on SSD in OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, ssd, virtual-memory

Should I, or do I need to, disable memory swapping when my OS is installed on an SSD? I run OSX 10.10.2 with 16GB of memory. Currently, Activity Monitor reports I have 16GB of virtual memory allocated, with 0Bytes actually being used. 5,28GB of Memory is in use.

I understand that it's beneficial for the longevity of as SSD to reduce the amount of write-actions to it, which leads me to believe it's also beneficial to not have a swap-file on that drive. If I really need one, can I move it to my internal HDD? If so: how?

Comment: If you're in doubt how it works, you shouldn't touch it. What makes you worried about it?

Comment: The longevity of an SSD is much more than the expected time you'll keep the Mac

Answer (score 1):

For how to do that, I recommend this excellent sophisticated answer: [How can I move virtual memory swap files to a different drive or partition?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/how-can-i-move-virtual-memory-swap-files-to-a-different-drive-or-partition)

But keep in mind that your SSD does NOT wear out as bad as most youngsters tell you. In fact, I experience HDs breaking a lot more often than SSDs. Besides, your computer only swaps if it's really necessary as it comes with enormous memory access speed penalties. And even if it was: I'd prefer keeping the swap on the SSD rather than moving it to a slow HD.

But always keep in mind: Storage media are expendable parts.