# Moving Virtual Memory (VM) partition from SSD to HDD - macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, partition, filesystem, customization

Currently my MacOS Catalina is installed onto my SSD. I have 128GB SSD and 3TB HDD. Half space of the SSD and large part of the HDD will be used for Linux that I am going to install. For MacOS I have around 60GB available on SSD and around 1.2TB on HDD.

I am looking for the best way (or all possible ways) to make my MacOS saving content of my VM partition (kernelcore, sleepimage and swap files) on my HDD.
I am looking for a way to either:

1. remove VM partition completely, force system to use /vm folder instead (not disk) as it used to be in the past, save /vm on HDD and make symlink to it on SSD in /private/var/
2. remove VM partition completely, make another VM partition on my HDD (**disk3s1**), and use that one instead
3. remove VM partition completely, use my whole MacOS partition (that is already being used for my user account - **disk1s2**) that resides on my HDD to save virtual memory files onto it

My disks list:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         60.5 GB    disk0s2
   3:           Linux Filesystem                         60.6 GB    disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI NO NAME                 536.9 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS MacOS HDD               1.2 TB     disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         29.5 GB    disk1s6
   4:           Linux Filesystem                         1.3 TB     disk1s3
   5:           Linux Filesystem                         500.1 GB   disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +60.5 GB    disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume MacOS SSD – dane        5.5 GB     disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 86.1 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                529.0 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk2s4
   5:                APFS Volume MacOS SSD               11.2 GB    disk2s5

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +29.5 GB    disk3
                                 Physical Store disk1s6
   1:                APFS Volume VM                      897.0 KB   disk3s1
```

I found similar question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375412/use-apfs-vm-volume-from-another-disk/375473#375473?newreg=9df45a0d3e5746eeaaf921a2e1850e08), however I can't make it working with the "**UPDATE: Simpler method**". I can't mount anything by using the fstab - when I did as it was described in the question from the link, my disk appears as unmounted and can't be mounted due to an error *(Error com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter: 49218)*. Also I can't unmount the original VM disk:

```
diskutil unmount /dev/disk2s4
Volume VM on disk2s4 failed to unmount: dissented by PID 0 (kernel_task)
```

With *sudo* prefix, it just freezes the terminal.

Also mounting a volume didn't work when I tried:

```
sudo diskutil mount -mountPoint /volumes/ disk3s1  
Volume on disk3s1 failed to mount
Perhaps the operation is not allowed by the invoking user (kDAReturnNotPrivileged)
This appears to be an APFS Volume; note that locked APFS volumes
will not mount unless unlocked (e.g. "diskutil apfs unlockVolume")
```

I also tried to mount to */private/var/vm* with the same result. Volume is not locked - when I tried *unlockVolume*.

At the end I can add that when I eddied *fstab* by adding this line:

```
UUID=<disk2s4 UUID here> none hfs rw,noauto
```

it still mounted to */private/var/vm*.

Comment: Why not just create a fusion container and let macOS decide which disk to use?

Comment: I presume this is an iMac. Won't putting all the VM on the mechanical hard drive have a significant effect on performance?  It would be much simpler to buy an external SSD and boot Linux off that.

Comment: I don't want to use any external drivers. Yes, it is upgraded iMac, I don't think it's an good idea to put Virtual Memory on its build-in SSD, I read its not very fast to save data. But anyway, I have 24GB of RAM (added), I don't want to save the sleepimage on partition that has 60GB. Disabling sleepimage would be one of very last options. I am not sure if I can put half of SSD and 1/3 of HDD into fusion. I don't want to give all the space of SSD and HDD to MacOS.

Comment: After experimenting with the system files, I went to a point where I had to reinstall everything from scratch. I took this opportunity to see if I can make a Fusion Drive only using part of my SSD and part of HDD. I looks like it is working, however I read somewhere it's not recommended. Officially Fusion Drive is supposed to be made of single platter-based HDD and SSD. I have 3TB HDD, I doubt it is single platter-based. I am wondering, why it's not recommended, what may go wrong, technically.